# Display multiple router components in a single view on Desktop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue.js to build a PWA. Despite the fact that this isn't a desktop browser app, I'm thinking of ways to better utilise the otherwise wasted real-estate by combining multiple views into a single larger view.

For example, on mobile, there are 2 views with distinct routes - Select Outlet and Order Items. Is there any way to combine both these views only for the desktop with minimal modification? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Abstract

I have a proposition of solution. Not sure if it will satisfy you but maybe it will give you a new perspective at least.

### Example

Router setup:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/combined-components',
    name: 'CombinedComponents',
    components: {
        default: WrapperComponent,
        'firs-component': SelectOutlet,
        'second-component': OrderItems
    },
}]
```

Template setup:

```
         <div class="wrapper-component">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="first-component">
                 <router-view name="first-component"></router-view>
               </div>
                <div v-if="isMobile" class="second-component">
                 <router-view name="second-component"></router-view>
               </div>
            </div>
         <div>
```

### Explanation

By using the `name` attribute for `<router-view>` we can decide which component will be displayed depending on the current route. So we have one parent component in this case `WrapperComponent` and inside it's template we can freely place another `<router-view>` and in `routes.js` (or just routes const that you pass to configure router) you can specify which component you want to be placed in the slot of `first-component` and `second-component`. That allows you to combine 2 of them and just proceed further routes without leaving `WrapperComponent`. Wha is left is to define if you should display the second component or not. Depending on `isMobile` that you can define yourself (I would assume based on screen width).

### Docs

Read more here: [Vue Router Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html)

### Summary

In this approach, it works from the other side. You prepare it for desktop and just restrict it for mobile.